# One-to-One or Many-to-One with CF9 ORM in 2 queries

Tags: sql, hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have two objects

```
HomeFeatures
<cfcomponent persistent="true">
    <cfproperty name="id" column="homeFeatureid">
    <cfproperty name="tabTitle">
    <cfproperty name="title">
    <cfproperty name="description">
    <cfproperty name="sort">
    <cfproperty name="moretext">
    <cfproperty name="url">
    <cfproperty name="active">
    <cfproperty name="media" fieldtype="many-to-one" fkcolumn="mediaid" cfc="media" lazy="false" fetch="join" missingrowIgnored="true">
</cfcomponent>
```

And

```
Media
<cfcomponent persistent="true" table="cms.dbo.media">
    <cfproperty name="id" column="mediaid">
    <cfproperty name="filename">
</cfcomponent>
```

Thus I have multiple homeFeatures, each of which has a media item associated with it. The same media item could be associated with multiple homeFeatures, but each homeFeature can only have one media item joined by homeFeatures.mediaid.

If I do an entityLoad("homeFeatures") I get 1 query for the homeFeatures and 1 query of the media table for EVERY ROW IN homeFeatures. In other words this is the N+1 problem. Why? This should be two queries total, one to get all of the homeFeatures, and one to get all of the media who's media ID is in the list determined by homeFeatures. I am attempting to do "eager" loading as defined at http://www.rupeshk.org/blog/index.php/2009/09/coldfusion-orm-performance-tuning-fetching-strategy/ and in the adobe docs.

In this specific view I need to access the media record for every entry, so that is why I have lazy set to false. I swear I have tried every iteration of lazy=false|true, batch=999, fieldtype=one-to-one|many-to-one, fetch=join|select, and all of them produce the same N+1 problem.

Any ideas? Please help!

Comment: So a `fetch="join"` still gets you many `SELECT`s from the child object? Have you ensured that you ran an `ORMReload()` after making changes to the objects?

Comment: Since this is a debug platform I have `ormReload()` in `onRequestStart()`. Also, I get a select statement for each parent object so the log repeats `select filename FROM media WHERE mediaid = (parents mediaid)` once for each parent DB row.

Comment: I'm on my iPad and can't get you the answer until tomorrow. Hang tight and don't do anything impractical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the solution is `batchsize`. By specifying on the cfc or on the cfproperty we are able to set a batchsize so that the related items are batched in groups, rather than individually.